# How to activate a sound in an if statement (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am writing a code for a game and I am almost done. I am at the point where I am trying to input sounds. What I did was insert the audiotoolbox framework and:

.h

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {

    SystemSoundID JumpSoundID;
}

-(void)jumpSound;

@end
```

and .m

```
@implementation GameViewController

-(void)jumpSound {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(JumpSoundID);
    NSURL *jumpURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"jump2" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)jumpURL, &JumpSoundID);

}
-(void)fishSound {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(FishSoundID);
    NSURL *fishURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pickupFish" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fishURL, &FishSoundID);
}
-(void)gameOverSound {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(GameOverSoundID);
    NSURL *gameOverURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"gameover" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)gameOverURL, &GameOverSoundID);
}
```

Then I thought I could simply call on the methods in the if statement like so:

```
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform.frame) && (upMovement <= -1 )){
    [self bounce];
    [self iceblockfall];
    [self jumpSound]; //this is what I thought I could call <<----------------
    if (iceblock6Used == NO) {
        addedScore = 1;
        iceblock6Used = YES;
    }
 }
```

But it is not working. Whenever I run it I get this error:

```
2014-02-28 18:03:52.383 BounceIt[528:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

*** First throw call stack..

What is the problem here. I am confused and can't find anything to help me. Am I making the wrong move by trying to call it as a method?

Comment: The error is clear. You are trying to create the URL with a nil string. Your wav file isn't there or the name is different - case matters.

Comment: Wow silly mistake. @rmaddy fixed it. Big thanks. Now for some reason it doesn't play the first time RectIntersectsRect, but does the second time? Any reason why as seen from that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(FishSoundID);
NSURL *fishURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pickupFish" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fishURL, &FishSoundID);
```

for this (move first line to the end)

```
NSURL *fishURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"pickupFish" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)fishURL, &FishSoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(FishSoundID);
```

But I would recommend moving the first two lines to your initialization code, it doesn't make sense loading the wav file every time.